# Why is this very simple UPDATE so much slower than the SELECT it contains?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update

In MariaDB 10.3.9:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos`

vs

`UPDATE counts SET countValue = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos) WHERE countName = 'photos';`

The select takes 1.1s vs the update which takes 2.6s.  3million rows in table `photos`, 3 rows in table `counts`.

`ANALYZE format=JSON` output:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 1299.6,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "photos",
      "access_type": "index",
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_length": "4",
      "used_key_parts": ["photoId"],
      "r_loops": 1,
      "rows": 3178665,
      "r_rows": 3.25e6,
      "r_total_time_ms": 1085.7,
      "filtered": 100,
      "r_filtered": 100,
      "using_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

vs

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 2764.7,
    "table": {
      "update": 1,
      "table_name": "counts",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": ["countName"],
      "key": "sCount",
      "key_length": "1023",
      "used_key_parts": ["countName"],
      "rows": 1,
      "r_rows": 1,
      "r_filtered": 100,
      "r_total_time_ms": 0.0756,
      "attached_condition": "counts.countName = 'photos'"
    },
    "subqueries": [
      {
        "query_block": {
          "select_id": 2,
          "r_loops": 1,
          "r_total_time_ms": 2764.6,
          "table": {
            "table_name": "photos",
            "access_type": "index",
            "key": "PRIMARY",
            "key_length": "4",
            "used_key_parts": ["photoId"],
            "r_loops": 1,
            "rows": 3178665,
            "r_rows": 3.25e6,
            "r_total_time_ms": 2541.8,
            "filtered": 100,
            "r_filtered": 100,
            "using_index": true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is the subquery in the update query so slow?  I can easily fix this by doing a separate manual update with the result of the select query, but I'd like to know why this is slowing down so much.

On further examination, even THIS takes over twice as long as the simple select:

`SET @foo = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos);`

What?  Why?!

Comment: `"key_length": "1"` vs `"key_length": "1023"` doesn't ring the bell?

Comment: Not really, can you spell it out for me?  That's on the `counts` table, why would that affect the speed of the `photos` table select?  Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob!

Comment: Comparison over the strings is slower than over the INTs. INTs are compared directly in the one operation while strings needs collations to be applied and then to be compared char by char. All slowdown is because of `WHERE countName = 'photos'`

Comment: Can you try this?: `UPDATE counts AS c CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_phootos FROM photos) AS p SET c.countValue = p.count_photos WHERE countName = 'photos';`

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
SELECT @ct := COUNT(*) FROM photos;
UPDATE counts SET countValue = @ct WHERE countName = 'photos';
```

Either have autocommit = ON, or at least don't put both statements in the same transaction.  This is to avoid locking `counts` while counting.

Also, `countName` should be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: I think I had it backward.  Please verify.